# Getting camera and lens from exif in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, exif

I use that code to get exif information from jpeg file. The data not include information about camera and lens manufacturer.

```
- (IBAction)readThis:(id)sender
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     NSString * fileName = @"/Users/joe/img.jpg" ;
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
    {
        NSBitmapImageRep * imageTest = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:fileName] ;
        NSLog(@"Exif Data in %@ : %@",fileName, [imageTest valueForProperty:@"NSImageEXIFData"]) ;
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"File %@ not found !",fileName) ;
    [pool release];

}
```

How to get data about camera and lens manufacturer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageIO framework. Refer this [link](http://caffeinatedcocoa.com/blog/?p=7) for setting and getting image metadata.